# How do I implement PHPMAILER with php procedural interface? I want to send verification emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I just uploaded my site to a live server and it no longer sends emails, web-host wants me to use PHPMAILER. The problem is my code is in procedural interface and PHPMAILER is in OOP. Please help me change OOP to procedural.

```html
$to      = $email; // Send email to our user
$subject = 'Signup | Verification'; // Give the email a subject
$message = '

Thanks for signing up!
Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by copying the url below
and pasting it in your brwoser.

------------------------
Username: '.$email.'
Password: '.$pass.'
------------------------

Please copy and paste this link in the address field and press enter to activate your account:<br>
http://elam.rpaz.co.zw/verify.php?email='.$email.'&password='.$cryptpass.'

'; // Our message above including the link

$headers = 'From:noreply@rpaz.co.zw' . "\r\n";
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "mail-2.sslzol.co.zw";
$mail->Port = 6465;
$mail->Username = 'noreply@jyvukyv';
$mail->Password = 'rp15kuyuelamhvkyu';
$mail->Subject = trim("Signup | Verification");
$mail->SetFrom('noreply@rpaz.co.zw', 'RPAZ e(LAM)');
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

try {
  $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $msg = $ex->getMessage();
}

echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($conn);

  header("Location: redirect.html");
     exit;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant see the problem here if u need to use PHPMailer just call it inside your PHP script/page. like

don't forget to included it inside your script in the start like

```
include 'RouteToPHPMailer/PHPMailer';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

and all that code u pasted up and will work.

Comment: I am having an error of mixing OOP and procedural. Please help

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp64\www\e(LAM)\reg.php on line 109